# Azure Analysis service deployment using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I am working on Azure Analysis service directly from portal.azure.com. Instead i want AAS be save as some file in git repo and deployed is managed through Azure DevOps. Not sure if this possible? How to proceed further on this

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure Analysis Service don’t support implementing using Azure Devops.

I would request you to provide the feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/556165-azure-analysis-services

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script task make a REST call to Azure from Azure DevOps, building the URL and payload from code, say passing in parameters, or by utilising a variable group.